# Grails g:if = null not working

Tags: grails, if-statement, null

I've been trying to put some if logic into my grails _form.gsp.  Basically I want it to add an extra line to a table if model I'm passing in is null, but its not working!

I have this: -

```
<g:if test="${results = null}">
    banana
</g:if>
```

And it does nothing.  I tried: -

```
<g:if test="${results.isEmpty()}">
```

But that causes the page to error on load with the message: -

```
Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null object
```

If I try the reverse logic with `<g:if test="${results != null}">` this works absolutely fine in scenarios where I know the model being passed in isn't empty!  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a double "==" for your if statement:

```
<g:if test="${results == null}">
                       ^
                       |
```

Comment: Doh, I can't believe I missed something quite that obivous.  suffering from tunnel vision!  Cheers!

Comment: Im happy that i was able to help and accept helpful answers please :)

Answer (score 1):

Since its Grails..

```
<g:if test="${ !results }">
```

would also work.. Just a shorter version